# projection based on svd

Tags: matrix-completion

Given a matrix $A$ with rank $r$. Suppose its reduced svd is $USV^{T}$.
Denote $E_{i,j}$ as matrix with only entry $(i,j)$ equaling to 1 and others all zeros.
Denote projection operator $P$ as
$$
  P(X) = U*U^{T}*X + X*V*V^{T} - U*U^{T}*X*V*V^{T}.
 $$

How to prove $<P(E_{i,j}),E_{i',j'}> = 0$ if $i\neq i'$ or $j\neq j'$,
where $<A,B> = trace(A^{T}\cdot B).$

Comment: In the SVD, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices, so $UU^T=I$ and $VV^T=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of the proper size. Then $P(X)=X$ and your question is trivial, since $\langle P(E_{i,j}), E_{i',j'}\rangle=\operatorname{trace}(E_{i,j}^T E_{i',j'})=\operatorname{trace}(0)=0$. Or am I missing something? Maybe $*$ is not matrix multiplication?